# Java lock and happend-before relation

Tags: java, concurrency, locking, java-memory-model, reentrantlock

I'm not sure if I'm interpreting the javadoc right. When using a `ReentrantLock` after calling the `lock` method and successfully gaining a lock, can you just access any object without any synchronized blocks and the happend-before relationship is magically enforced?

I don't see any connection between the `ReentrantLock` and the objects I'm working on, that's why it is hard to believe I can work on them safely. But this is the case, or am I reading the javadoc wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If thread A has modified some object inside a code block CB1 guarded by the lock and then releases the lock, and thread B enters in a code block guarded by the same lock, then thread B will see the modifications done by thread A in the code block CB1.

If two threads read and write the same shared state, then every read and write to this state should be guarded by the same lock.

Answer (score 2):

It's ... a (mutex) lock:

```
void myMethod()
{

    myLock.lock();  // block until condition holds
    try 
    {
         // Do stuff that only one thread at a time should do
     } 
     finally 
     {
         myLock.unlock()
     }
}
```

Only one thread can hold the lock at a time, so anything between the `lock()` and `unlock()` calls is guaranteed to only be executed by one thread at a time.

[The relevant Oracle tutorial can be found here.](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/newlocks.html)

Comment: Yeah thanks, I understand that they are executed exclusively but my question was aiming at if the same state will be seen from different threads.

Comment: What you're talking about is how java caches variables in each thread. Use of the lock (or use of the `synchronized` keyword) guarantees a synchronization. [This SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5022100/when-does-java-thread-cache-refresh-happens) I think answers your question more fully. Specifically section 17.1 of the JLS

Answer (score 2):

There's no magic in it. You're safe if, and only if, all threads accessing an object use the same lock - be it a `ReentrantLock` or any other mutex, such as a `synchronized` block.

The existence `ReentrantLock` is justified by that it provides more flexibility than `synchronized`: you can, for example, just *try* to acquire the lock - not possible with `synchronized`.