# synchronization on single statement?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

if I have a getter method that has only one statement like this

```
public class NumberClass{
    int number;

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
    ...
}
```

and multiple threads access this method, do I have to synchronize this method or it is not necessary since it has only one statement??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I have to synchronize this [get] method or it is not necessary since it has only one statement??

It has nothing to do with 1 or more statements.  It depends on whether or not the value has been updated in another thread and if you want all of the threads to see a consistent value.

If the `number` field was updated in thread1, then thread2 may get either the original value or  the new value depending on how the update was synchronized.  To have the value published appropriately both the set and get methods need to `synchronized`.

If you are just trying to share an `int` value then marking the `number` field as being `volatile` would work or using an `AtomicInteger` to share the value between multiple threads reliably may be more appropriate.

```
private volatile int number;
```

or use:

```
private AtomicInteger number = new AtomicInteger();
```

Comment: I also have similar question related to synchronization [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47783712/do-not-share-same-socket-between-two-threads-at-the-same-time/) where I am using synchronization on socket object and I am trying to see whether I can get rid of synchronization altogether or not through some other efficient way? Wanted to see if you can help out.

Comment: He did @DavidSchwartz.  There's a link to his question in the comment.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes**, it may be a good idea to synchronize that statement. The reason is that each thread is, according to spec, allowed to **cache its own version of the variable**. To se it demonstrated, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787094/how-to-demonstrate-java-multithreading-visibility-problems).

Other options are to

- Make the variable volatile:

  ```
  volatile int number;
  ```
- or to use [`AtomicInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) from the java.util.concurrent package:

  ```
  AtomicInteger number;
  ```

---

As a side-note: If `number` had been of type `long`, not even a *read* of the variable would have been atomic (one thread could rewrite the value of the variable in the *middle* of a read). See [Chapter 17.7: Non-atomic Treatment of double and long](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html) of the Java Language Specification.

Answer (score 1):

You need a memory barrier, or other threads are not guaranteed to see the "correct" value (meaning, any value that is explicitly assigned to `number`).

To fix this, declare `number` as a `final` or `volatile` member, or access it from a `synchronized` block.

The number of statements, contrary to some other answers, *is* a consideration. You do not need atomicity (because it's a single statement), so using `synchronized` is probably overkill. If the value changes, use `volatile`, and if it doesn't, use `final`. If you had multiple statements that needed to appear as acting atomically, `synchronized` would be the only option.