# Complete example for use of volatile key word in Java?

Tags: java, volatile

I need a simple example of use of the `volatile` keyword in Java, behaving inconsistently as a result of not using `volatile`.

The theory part of *volatile* usage is already clear to me.

Comment: If you already know about the theory, why don't you just try something?

Answer (score 13):

First of all, there's no *guaranteed* way of exposing caching due to non-volatile variables. Your JVM might just be very kind to you all the time and effectively treat every variable as volatile.

That being said, there are a few ways to increase probability of having threads caching their own versions of a non-volatile variable. Here is a program that exposes the importance of volatile in most machines I've tested it on (adapted version from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787094/how-to-demonstrate-java-multithreading-visibility-problems)):

```
class Test extends Thread {

    boolean keepRunning = true;

    public void run() {
        while (keepRunning) {
        }

        System.out.println("Thread terminated.");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Test t = new Test();
        t.start();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        t.keepRunning = false;
        System.out.println("keepRunning set to false.");
    }
}
```

This program will typically just output

```
keepRunning set to false.
```

and continue running. Making `keepRunning` volatile causes it to print

```
keepRunning set to false.
Thread terminated.
```

and terminate.

Comment: Funny, if you make the loop do something, the example will no longer work (e.g. `System.out.println(".");` inside `while(keepRunning)`

Comment: it's because `System.out.println(...) is synchronized ` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17748078/simplest-and-understandable-example-of-volatile-keyword-in-java