# How to simulate in Java a stale value read by a thread?

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization

I would like to simulate a situation which is mentioned in books about concurrency - that without a proper synchronization one thread can see a stale value of a variable that has been already modified by a different thread. This could happen because for example a CPU cache.

To do this I have written the following program. The idea is that there are 4 threads that initialize a different part of a shared array. The 5th thread (main, parent thread) waits until all 4 previous threads are done, iterates over the shared array and adds its values (always 1 or if I'm lucky null, which would mean a stale value)

```
package p1;

class ArrFill implements Runnable {
    int l, r;
    Integer[] arr;
    ArrFill(int l, int r, Integer[] arr) {
        this.l = l;
        this.r = r;
        this.arr = arr;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int i = l; i < r; i++)
            arr[i] = new Integer(1);
    }
}

public class Main {

    final static int MAX = 10000000;
    final static int tnum = 4;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        int cores = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
        System.out.println(cores);

        Integer[] arr = new Integer[MAX];
        Thread[] t = new Thread[tnum];

        if(MAX % tnum != 0)
            throw new IllegalStateException();

        int step = MAX / tnum;
        int l = 0, r = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < tnum; i++) {
            l = r;
            r += step;
            t[i] = new Thread(new ArrFill(l, r, arr));
            t[i].start();
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < tnum; i++)
            t[i].join();

        int res = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
            if(arr[i] != null)
                res += arr[i];

        System.out.println(res == MAX);
    }
}
```

I have run this program many times although I never seen a stale value (null). I have 2 cores. Do you have any idea how this program could be improved to actually present the cached value phenomena? Or maybe you have a completly different approach?

Thanks!

Comment: To be clear, you don't want to simulate this condition, you want to reproduce it, right?

Comment: Calling `join()` guarantees that you won't see outdated values because it establishes a happens-before relationship between everything that happened in the thread with what happens afterwards in the main thread.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to demonstrate java multithreading visibility problems?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787094/how-to-demonstrate-java-multithreading-visibility-problems)