# Executor System.out.println not showing in console

Tags: java, scheduledexecutorservice

```
package com.company;

import java.io.Console;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Main {

    static boolean isToastShewnLeft = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        showToastLeft("first", "", "");
        showToastLeft("second", "", "");
        showToastLeft("third", "", "");
        showToastLeft("fourth", "", "");
        showToastLeft("fifth", "", "");
    }

    public static void showToastLeft(final String paramToastString1, final String paramToastString2, final String paramToastString3) {

        final long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        ScheduledExecutorService worker1 = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

        ScheduledExecutorService worker2 = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

        if (isToastShewnLeft) {

            final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
                public void run() {
                    while (isToastShewnLeft) {

                    }

                    isToastShewnLeft = true;

                    //This line does not appear in console output
                    //I can set a breakpoint on this println and see that it does execute
                    System.out.println(paramToastString1);

                    ScheduledExecutorService worker3 = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

                    final Runnable r2 = new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            isToastShewnLeft = false;

                            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - start + " Set toast not shewn");
                        }
                    };

                    worker3.schedule(r2, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

                }
            };

            worker1.schedule(r, 0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        } else {
            isToastShewnLeft = true;

            System.out.println(paramToastString1);

            final Runnable r2 = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    isToastShewnLeft = false;
                    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - start + " Set toast not shewn");
                }
            };

            worker2.schedule(r2, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        }
    }
}
            /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Didea.launcher.port=7543 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14 CE.app/Contents/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ant-javafx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javafx-doclet.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javafx-mx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jconsole.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/htmlconverter.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfxrt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/Users/ericsepich/IdeaProjects/untitled1/out/production/untitled1:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14 CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain com.company.Main
            first
            5008 Set toast not shewn
```

My intent is to show the texts 5 seconds apart at each call to showToastLeft. Is it possible that there is a problem using println from 
the executors thread? I am using IntelliJ idea as my IDE.

I will be posting a screenshot showing the value of the boolean to be true in my debugger.
[image]

Thank you for any responses....

Comment: So the only output you see is `first` and then `5008 Set toast not shewn`?

Comment: Correct. Is it possible there is threading problem with println?

Comment: I made a copy paste example that can be pasted into IntelliJ. I'm currently in a Yosemite environment. I think the JDK version is posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not letting the Java threading system a chance to share the CPU between your threads.

```
                while (isToastShewnLeft) {
                  // Add this.
                  Thread.sleep(10);
                }
```

Comment: The sleep in this location seems to be a critical addition. It doesn't work without the sleep in the while.

Comment: The ordering is something I have to work out if I can't figure it out I may have to post another question about that. Thank you very much these are very enlightening posts.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple threads reading and writing the `isToastShewnLeft` variable without any concurrency protection.  Try enclosing all read/write operations on `isToastShewnLeft` in `synchronized` and see if this makes a difference.  The issue here may be a thread-related visibility problem: the subtle situation where threads keep their own copies of variables and reorder operations for efficiency.  Synchronization is one way of preventing this with any shared variables.  [Here is one good explanation of visibility](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/08/java-concurrency-tutorial-visibility-between-threads.html), and [here is another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787094/how-to-demonstrate-java-multithreading-visibility-problems).

Besides `synchronized`, you could use a [`java.util.concurrent.AtomicBoolean`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html), if let's say you were really concerned about performance (which I doubt given the 5 seconds intervals).  It's a bit more subjective whether you could get away with just making `isToastShewnLeft` into a `volatile` variable, but I would shy away from that given that the state of `isToastShewnLeft` affects what is written to it.

Comment: Generally I think I understand what you are saying and I need to read up on those articles. Right now the part that I am thinking about is that now that toast are showing at the proper interval but they are not in succession. The order is changed.