# How does Thread.yield prevent a print statement from executing in a while loop given that the main thread changes the 'while' condition

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

Below is the example code of the problem:We a have  main thread and another thread which calls the enters the run function.

```
public class WhatDoesThisDo {

private static boolean ready;

private static int number;



private static class ReaderThread extends Thread {

    public void run() {

        while (!ready)

            Thread.yield();



        System.out.println(number);

    }       

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    new ReaderThread().start();

    number = 42;

    ready = true;

}
```

}

The correct answer according to some is that it either prints 42, 0 or nothing. Please explain why it can print nothing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18475832/1553851

Comment: The correct answer is that the behaviour is undefined, because the variables aren't `volatile`.

Comment: `ReaderThread` might never see `ready` being set to `true` and go into infinite loop.