# Java: synchronization does not block if it changes

Tags: java, multithreading

Related [Java will synchronized block if changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56281291/java-will-synchronized-block-if-changed)

```
 public class TestConcurrentTwo {
     public static void main(String[] args) {

         class lock {
             public Object lockObj = new Object();
             int protectedValue = 0;
         }
         lock a = new lock();

         Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
             try {
                 synchronized (a.lockObj) {
                     System.out.println("from first block start");
                     System.out.println(a.protectedValue);
                     a.lockObj = new Object();
                     Thread.sleep(1000);
                     System.out.println(a.protectedValue);
                     System.out.println("from first block done");
                 }
             } catch (InterruptedException x) {}
         });
         t.start();
         try {
             Thread.sleep(100);
         } catch (InterruptedException x) {}

         synchronized (a.lockObj) {
             System.out.println("from second block start");
             a.protectedValue++;
             System.out.println("from second block done");
         }

         System.out.println(a.protectedValue);
     }
 }
```

OUTPUT:

```
from first block start
0
from second block start
from second block done
1
1
from first block done
```

In the related answer, they both hold the original reference so the second block should be blocked until the completion of the first.

However, second block indeed proceeded once `a.lockObj` changed from first block. why?

Comment: Your two threads are using different locks.  The first thread is holding the first Object instance referenced by a,lockObj, the second thread is holding the second Object instance referenced by a.lockObj.  This is easy to avoid: *do not reallocate objects you are synchronizing on*.

Comment: Some of the wording in that other answer is IMO confusing, specifically the use of the word "reference",  Let us call the member ```a.lockObj``` a **reference**; the ```Object``` referenced by ```a.lockObj``` is the **referenced object**.  The synchronization depends on the referenced object, not on the reference.  There are two different referenced objects being used for synchronization; result misery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating **two** objects, so let's name them for our reference:

- *ObjA* created in the field initializer
- *ObjB* created in the line right before `sleep(1000)`

The `synchronized (a.lockObj)` block in the thread is locking on *ObjA*.

Since you have `sleep(100)` after starting the thread, the thread will have changed `a.lockObj` to refer to *ObjB* by the time the main thread reaches its `synchronized (a.lockObj)` block, so that will **lock on a different object**.

Being a different object, the code will not block.

*Hint:* The lock is on the object, not the reference variable.